# Boost Thread Destructor Undefined Symbol

Tags: c++, boost-asio, undefined-symbol

I'm using OSX Mountain Lion. I just downloaded, unpacked, and built boost 1.52.0 using the instructions supplied from the boost website: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html. I left the default installation prefix at `/usr/local`, meaning that the libraries are installed in `/usr/local/lib` and the header files are in `/usr/local/include`. I have verified that the libraries and headers are present there and recently modified.

I'm attempting to compile the boost asynchronous I/O example found here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer5/src.html (source).

Here is my compilation command:

```
g++ -Wall -c -g -I/usr/local/include src/test1.cpp -o src/test1.o
```

where src/test1.cpp is the example source file. Here is my linking command (and error):

```
g++ -Wall -L/usr/local/lib -lboost_thread -lboost_system  src/test1.o -o bin/test1
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::thread::~thread()", referenced from:
      _main in test1.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have tried using both Apple's clang++ 4.0 and g++ 4.6.0. I get the same undefined symbol error from both programs.

Other people seem to have had trouble compiling this code sample as well. I am aware of this question: [C++ / Boost: Undefined Symbols in example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820269/c-boost-undefined-symbols-in-example) and this one: [Linker error when compiling boost.asio example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568243/linker-error-when-compiling-boost-asio-example). However, each of these problems seems to have been fixed by adding the appropriate switches (-lboost_thread and -lboost_system) to the command line. I already have those. I have also tried adding -lpthread without luck.

Thank you for taking time to look at my question! Any help is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just ran into this same problem, and I found that reverting to Boost 1.49 fixes the problem.  Download links for Boost 1.49 are here:

http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_49_0.html

Before installing 1.49, I removed 1.52 by deleting `/usr/local/include/boost` and `/usr/local/lib/*boost*`.  Not sure what changed between 1.49 and 1.52 to cause this problem, or whether Boost 1.50 or 1.51 will work.

Answer (score 0):

Put the libraries you link with *last* on the command line.

The GNU linker uses kind of reverse lookup of dependencies, so if file A depends on library B, B should come *after* A on the command line.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I moved the libraries to the end of the linker command, and re-ordered them (all six different orders of the three arguments -lpthread, -lboost_thread, and -lboost_system), but to no avail. I received the same error every time.

Perhaps this is relevant: when I add the flag `-static`, I get a different error: `ld: library not found for -lcrt0.o`. I never mentioned that file on the command-line.

I can confirm that both the .a and .dylib versions of each library are installed under `/usr/local/lib`.